# Struggling to Animate Fullpage.js Slides with GSAP

Tags: javascript

I'm using Fullpage.js and GSAP to animate a website that I am building for fun. I have managed to get animations to play when sections are going up and down but I am really struggling to do the same for Slides.

From below, I am trying to go to the slide on the right and have the title -   move down and fade in. The slide will display but no animation plays?

Any help would be appreciated! :D

```
/*==============================
    MOVING LEFT/RIGHT BETWEEN SLIDES
    ==============================*/
    onSlideLeave:(section, origin, destination, direction) => {
    var section = destination.item;
    const title = section.querySelector(".slidesTitles"); //Selects h1
    const tlSlides = new TimelineMax({ delay: 0.4});
    
    /*==================
    WHO WE ARE SECTION
    ==================*/
    //Right from Slide 0 (Default) to Slide 1
      if(section.index === 1 && origin.index === 0 && direction === 'right'){
        tlSlides.fromTo(title, 0.5, { y: "30", opacity: 0 }, { y: "0", opacity: 1 }, 0.05); //moves the h1 title down
        }
```